# Keras: Question about early stopping network state

Tags: tensorflow, keras

First off: I know what early stopping is and why it is important. However, I do have a question concerning the Keras implementation of this technique:

If I specify a patience parameter and the observed value does not improve any further; does Keras return the state my network had at the point with the lowest observed value or does Keras return the network state at the point the patience "ran out"?

Put in other words:

Let s_0 be the state of my network at epoch t_0 (in which the lowest value of my observed metric is recorded). Let x be the patience value and s_x be the state of my network at epoch t_x. If the training stops, does Keras return s_0 or s_x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does Keras return the network state at the point the patience "ran out"? -- `YES!`

From Keras documentation of [EarlyStopping](https://keras.io/callbacks/#earlystopping):

- `patience`: number of epochs with no improvement ***after which*** training will be stopped.